# Kinematics of a particle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, time, velocity, distance

> A swimmer jumps using a spring board. The board bends with distance $-X_0$. Then it accelerates him with $a_c = - \omega^2 x$ with $\omega =\mathrm{const}$. He loses contact at $x=0$, then he flies vertically upward with $a_f = -g$. Air resistance negligible.

Actually, I want to ask a simple question. I've already got $v(s) = \omega \sqrt{x_0^2-x^2}$, then I want to search for the distance $x$ as function of time $t$, but I don't know how to integrate it, as the right answer is

$x(t) = x_0 \sin(\omega t -{\pi\over 2})$

I don't get the idea how the $\pi$ comes from. Any help would be very appreciated.

Additional question:

> What is the distance between the unloaded board and the surface of the water $x_{hit}$, if the swimmer hits the water with $v_{hit} = -2 \omega x_0$.

I've calculated the $v(x), x(t), v(t)$ but it looks like $x_{hit}$ doesn't depends on those 3 equations?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is the same as $x(t)=x_0cos(\omega t)$, which is a solution to the differential equation $\ddot x = - \omega^2 x$, the equation of Simple Harmonic Motion (SHM).

Note that $v(t)=\dot x(t)=-\omega x_0 sin(\omega t)$.

Comment: Thank you so much, so the amplitude $A$ is $x$ and the $y$ is $x_0$ in the SHM equation, right? Also, I have another problem, I've edited the question. Maybe you can help me again?

Comment: Amplitude is $x_0$ as given in the question. $x$ is measured vertically. For the additional question, look at conservation of energy, from $x=0$ to $x=-x_{hit}$.

Comment: Actually, they wrote the answer like this: $v(t) = - \omega x_0-gt$, then we got the value of $t$, then insert the value of $t$ and the given $v_{hit}$ into the equation $x(t) = - \omega x_0t-{1\over 2}gt^2$. But the problem is I don't know how to get the equation of $v(t) = - \omega x_0-gt$...

Comment: That eqn is just the usual kinematic eqn v=u+at.